# Broadcast ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED or ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED not invoked when installing apk from AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android project with 2 apps.

AppA register a receiver for the actions `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` or `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` from code (not in it's Manifest).

When I install AppB from command line with `adb install AppB.apk` I see that the BroadcastReceiver from AppA receive a broadcast intent as expected.

When I deploy AppB directly from AndroidStudio (with launch debug button) : the BroadcastReceiver from AppA don't receive any broadcast intent.

Is it expected ? and is there anything to do/setup in AndroidStudio to force the broadcast also when apk is deployed with the launch debug button ?

What I tried ?

**Attempt 1:**

I made a test with option "Always install with PackageManager" checked (in AndroidStudio launch configuration window), but it don't help.

**Attempt 2:**

AndroidStudio launch configuration offer the ability to execute an external tool before launch. So I tried to explicitly broadcast the PACKAGE_ADDED action by executing : `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED -d com.company.app.b -t package` just before launch of AppB.

Unfortunately, this generate a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` which is not really surprising as PACKAGE_ADDED is of course a protected broadcast.

Comment: Is it also not firing with ./gradlew installDebug ? My first thought was the enabled hotreload feature in AS which may not trigger those broadcasts.

Answer (score 1):

can you disable **instant run** android studio and try. when the instant run is enabled Android studio is able to replace the dex file directly maybe that is the potential reason you are not getting ADDED or REPLACE action.

Comment: I can't find the option to disable "instant run" (I'm using Bumble Bee). (I have a checkbox :   "deploy as instant app", but it is unchecked and disabled for my apps.)

Comment: @ben75 can you disable that option and try?

Comment: I try to disable "parallel run" and also "deploy as instant app"... but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a broadcast from B app with specified Action name and register it in app A

Comment: I'm afraid that it won't solve anything. First: it seems a bad idea to workaround a problem apparently caused by IDE with a modification of production code. But also : this broadcast Intent won't be triggered when package is installed 'normally'.